# How can I make Paperclip's attachment path value immutable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, paperclip, immutability

The Rails plug-in Paperclip interpolates the attachment path based on some dynamic user-defined rules each time the path is requested.  This allows you to put names/IDs/etc. into the paths of your attachments.

However, I have two cases where the original path dependencies can change, and when they do I can no longer find the attachment anymore, because the interpolated path now points to the wrong place.

I need the path to be interpolated just once, when the file is saved, then that path preserved and returned there after regardless of the interpolation dependencies changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a colleague of mine came up with a good solution.  it's not seamlessly integrated into paperclip but it's effective.  the gist is:

1. using a "before_create" filter on the model to take a snapshot of all the values used in the path that could change
2. referencing those snapshotted values from the paperclip path interpolation (as opposed to the actual source, which could change)

so your path definition looks something like this:

```
:path => '.../:snapshotted_name/...'
```

and the code looks something like this:

```
before_create :snapshot_names # only set once

private

def snapshot_names
  snapshotted_name = customer.name
end
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the problem.

> I have two cases where the original path dependencies can change

Why will they change? What are these two cases? What is preventing you from coming up with a scheme whereby they will never change?

Comment: an example is something like "/customer_name/product_name/" where either the customer or the product name can change in the future but the paths to the files will not, thus interpolating the paths will break when those names change.

Comment: Then interpolate using IDs or something else. In other words, come up with a scheme whereby the paths will never change. Figure out what doesn't change, and then base the paths on that.